# Ignore a specific tag in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I am building a site using Jekyll and I have something that looks like `{{ }}` (a liquid tag) in my code. I want this to end up in the output html after Jekyll finishes generating the site, but Jekyll interprets it like any other tag. Is there a way to make Jekyll ignore just this specific instance of this tag?

Comment: That {{ }} is called as `Liquid`. https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers

Comment: Right. That's why I tagged "Liquid" in this question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16256799/revisions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `{% raw %}` tag:

```
{% raw %}
  {{ ... }}
{% endraw %}
```

This snippet will produce `{{ ... }}`.